# 3 D array representation

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

Suppose we have an array a[90][30][40] where first element starts from a[1][1][1] then what will be the index of a[20][20][30] in column major representation ?

According to me a[x][y][z] means x is depth, y is rows and z is columns.

So according to me, the index should be 19(30)(40) + (29)(30) + (20-1) = 23689.

I read https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/memory-layout-of-multi-dimensional-arrays/  which says that a[x][y][z] actually means x is rows, y is columns and z is depth.

I read all the existing answers here and also the above link and got confused.

Is my calculation correct?

Comment: The first element is actually `a[0][0][0]`.

Comment: What did you try to sort it out yourself - probably nothing.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 what else you want me to sort out ? I showed the calculation and also the link I read.

Comment: To do some experiments. This is the proper way of learning

Comment: The formula is in the link you posted too, given an `int a[rows][cols][layers];`, element `a[i][j][k]` has an offset of `k + layers * (j + cols * i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked you in the comment what have you done to sort this puzzle out? Not your "calculations". It is enough to write three lines of the code to get the answer:

```
char a[10][10][10];


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("&a[%1d][0][0] = %04zu\t\t&a[0][%1d][0] = %04zu\t\t&a[0][0][%1d] = %04zu\n", i, &a[i][0][0] - &a[0][0][0], i, &a[0][i][0] - &a[0][0][0], i, &a[0][0][i] - &a[0][0][0]);


&a[0][0][0] = 0000              &a[0][0][0] = 0000              &a[0][0][0] = 0000
&a[1][0][0] = 0100              &a[0][1][0] = 0010              &a[0][0][1] = 0001
&a[2][0][0] = 0200              &a[0][2][0] = 0020              &a[0][0][2] = 0002
&a[3][0][0] = 0300              &a[0][3][0] = 0030              &a[0][0][3] = 0003
&a[4][0][0] = 0400              &a[0][4][0] = 0040              &a[0][0][4] = 0004
&a[5][0][0] = 0500              &a[0][5][0] = 0050              &a[0][0][5] = 0005
&a[6][0][0] = 0600              &a[0][6][0] = 0060              &a[0][0][6] = 0006
&a[7][0][0] = 0700              &a[0][7][0] = 0070              &a[0][0][7] = 0007
&a[8][0][0] = 0800              &a[0][8][0] = 0080              &a[0][0][8] = 0008
&a[9][0][0] = 0900              &a[0][9][0] = 0090              &a[0][0][9] = 0009
```

Comment: So was my calculation correct ? Even I took the representation as <depth,row,column>.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my calculation correct?

No, since your basis is wrong.

The first element is `a[0][0][0]`, since indexing starts from 0 in arrays, not 1.

Usually, the first dimension of a 3D array is the rows, the second the columns, and the third the depth.

There are two popular representation when it comes to arrays, [row and column major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).

---

It seems like you are confused and talk about Fortran arrays (where the arrays are column major ordered, and the index starts from 1), rather than C ones.

Comment: Then how will the calculation be ? I am not able to visualize the column major representation of 3d array.

Comment: If possible please help me in visualizing the column major representation. I am not interested in base index at the moment.

Comment: C is row major ordered when it comes to arrays @Zephyr. I am not sure what you are asking me.

Comment: `visualizing the column major representation`. First index is the page with the table, the second one is the row in the table on this page, the third is the column

Comment: @PeterJ_01 But in the website the representation is different. It's <row,column,depth>

Comment: @Zephyr this is row major.

Comment: Logically it does not matter if you will always use indexes, but if you try to copy elements using memcpy for example the real orderings matters. So what you trust more - the compiler output or some mythic website.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I trusted the website first because of comments below the website which said well written and all..